# in app purchase complete method doesn't fire

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I want to use in app purchase in my application. I was on target with examples. Everything works normally until completing in app purchase. I can buy the product. it should call the handler after completed the process but it doesn't work. So the product is not given to user.

The code part is as follows:

```
BillingHelper.requestPurchase(activity, productId); 
Handler mTransactionHandler = new Handler(){

@Override
public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
   Log.i(TAG, "Transaction complete");
   Log.i(TAG, "Transaction status: "+BillingHelper.latestPurchase.purchaseState);
   Log.i(TAG, "Item purchased is: "+BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId);
   if(BillingHelper.latestPurchase.isPurchased()){
            // my code is here
       }     
    };
};

startService(new Intent(activity, BillingService.class));
BillingHelper.setCompletedHandler(mTransactionHandler);
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: which version you are using v2 or v3?

Comment: use V3 because V3 is very easy to integrate in application see http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html for more info